# How do I perform logical operations without a micro-controller?

Tags: analog, logic-gates

I would like to build some (hopefully) simple logic circuits without the use of a microcontroller. I'm a software engineer primarily so I think of things slightly differently. To implement this with a microcontroller would be simple but I want to learn how to do it without.

Take the following image. Imagine four photoresistors separated by some baffles. As a light travels around this, each photoresistor would change it's resistance in response to the light, obviously.

[image: Fig 1]

If I had this mounted on a two-axis pan-tilt mount, I could track the light with the following simple pseudocode:

```
# primary axis
if (A+C > B+D) rotateRight()
else if (A+C < B+D) rotateLeft()

# secondary axis
if (A+B > C+D) tiltUp()
else if (A+B < C+D) tiltDown()
```

Now say I have four LEDs, I want to light them up depending on where the light is. I essentially have four inputs and would like to electronically do this:

```
LED 1 = A+C > B+D
LED 2 = A+C < B+D
LED 3 = A+B > C+D
LED 4 = A+B < C+D
```

How would you go about that? Is it possible (/viable) with standard transistors or would you need specific chips? Is there a simple way of doing this?

I look forward to hearing back from everyone!

Thanks

Comment: Comparators and logic gates.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: But if you actually want to track a light source with the photocells and pan/tilt actuator it's really a control problem and you need to make sure the system is stable by applying control theory to the feedback loop.

Comment: Your title is misleading, the real problem is how to make a Control loop with out microcontroller. Because, it isn"t just a basic logic problem.

Comment: What John D said, plus this type of problem you describe has been solved with microcontrollers for the better part of 30 years. As a software guy, that is your opportunity to succeed. Trying to solve that problem in hardware is not trivial. I guarantee you will fail hard, come back here for help, probably not get a good answer because the problem is too localized, get discouraged, and give up. Use a microcontroller, and complete your project.

Comment: @MathieuL I disagree. While his end goal appears to be a control loop, the question is just about lighting up some LEDs based on analog voltage comparisons.

Comment: @MattYoung This problem isn't nearly as difficult as you're making it out to be - see pjc50's link for an example - and I think you're doing the OP a disservice by trying to discourage him from trying.

Comment: @NickJohnson I think you're doing the OP a disservice by oversimplifying.

Comment: @NickJohnson, Actually re-reading carefully, you are kinda right. He could do with a couple comparator + amp op in open loop.

Comment: @MattYoung What makes you think it'll be vastly more complex than a 2d application of the line following robot mentioned in pjc50's link?

Comment: @NickJohnson It's not complexity, it's getting the system stable. That's a lot easier to do digitally.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the feedback and discussion, and agree both ways. If it's a case of getting the project working quickly then sure, a microprocessor makes the job easy and is the obvious way to go. This particular question is more of a learning exercise for me to plug a hole in my knowledge. From all the feedback I have a clear idea of how this simple operation would be formed along with the caveats I would face in using this in the actually control loop. Thanks to all for the discussion though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can average two analog voltages - which is equivalent to adding them, effectively -  with a resistor divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjxck3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This only works if your inputs, A and B, have low impedance compared to R1 and R2 - that is, they're capable of supplying a lot more current than these resistors will draw, meaning their voltage won't be affected much by the divider. That's definitely not the case for something like a photodiode, so you'll need a buffer that measures the photodiode signal and reproduces it with much lower impedance - something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTn1Ke.png)</sup>

To compare voltages, you want a comparator. A comparator takes two inputs, and outputs a high voltage if the positive input is greater than the negative input, and a low voltage otherwise.

Collectively, you'd configure the whole thing something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1hW8L.png)</sup>

For each of the other outputs, you could reuse the opamp buffers, but use separate resistors and comparators to sum the outputs you need.

Comment: +1 looks good except I think you want the photodiodes reverse biased (so flipped vertically and swapped with the resistors).

Comment: Thanks Nick, this is a great starting point for me to do some research and exactly the kind of diagram I was after. I could trip this down to two inputs and take it from there to understand what is going on. Very educational and to the point. Thanks mate!

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Oops, I'm an idiot. Fixed!

Answer (score 5):

The one-dimensional version of this, with just two sensors and a line between them, is the classic line follower robot. Plenty of analog solutions exist. Here's one, for example, involving converting signals to PWM using op-amps: http://www.ermicro.com/blog/?p=1908

Comment: Excellent reference addressing the ultimate question, and a really good read.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to go a bit advanced (for me) but that's great, it gives me a lot of topics to research and a lot to learn, with a working solution in the end.

Comment: @AdamKDean Definitely work on it - once you can understand the circuit in that link you're most of the way to understanding everything involved. LTSpice is a great tool for this sort of thing too, to simulate the circuits involved.

Answer (score 3):

The device that compares two voltages is called a [comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator). It's certainly possible to build one from discrete transistors, but it's also available as a commodity IC. [LM319](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm119.pdf) is an extremely common and classic comparator.

With comarators, you can implement the "<" and ">" operations if you can represent "brightness on a sensor" as a voltage.

The other part is the addition operation. The canonical solution, for analog voltages, is the [summing amplifier](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_4.html), which can be constructed with a handful of resistors and an [operational amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier).

Of course there are a lot of details to work out, so I'd encourage you to begin with a simpler goal. However, reading about these two basic circuits should give you ample footing to begin experimenting.

Comment: Thanks Phil, appreciate the links in this post. Part of this exercise is not only to learn how to do something but also to gauge how simple it would be. Something which is super easy with a microcontroller might be really advanced without one, but the only way of finding out is to ask the community. There are some good links for me to go away and study here, and some good direction. Thanks again!